# running source activate <env> in Anacaonda Promt fails

Tags: anaconda

There are already many posts describing how to solve 'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command," by adding anaconda to path.
Following the recommended approach is to not check the box to add Anaconda to your path.

How can i start my env from the Anaconda Promt?
conda 4.6.11
conda env list show my env's

Answer (score 0):

`conda activate environmentNameHere` in the Anaconda terminal will do it. If you want to deactivate an environment you just type `conda deactivate`